# Does typescript allow calling keys of interface dynamically

Tags: typescript

I have a interface :

```js
interface MyInterface {
   field_1 : string
   field_2 : string
   // ... other fields with a certain number
}
```

And I have a getter function that receives an instance of MyInterface  and should retrieve a value of an attribute of this object dynamically

```js
const myFactory = (myInstance:MyInterface):string => { 
    // Here some logic to retrieve a specific number 
    // for convenience lets say that the output of this logic is 1
    let output = 1
    return myInstance[`field_${output}`] // <=== This does not work since it calls a property of the interface dynmically
}
```

How can I call a property of an interface dynamically ?

I saw the [`keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html) :
but I am not sure how to use it here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1:

```
  type myKey = `field_${'1' | '2' | '3'}`

  const output = '3'
  const fieldKey: myKey = `field_${output}`
```

Option 2:

```
 const fieldKey = `field_${output}` as keyof MyInterface
 return myInstance[fieldKey]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `as` keyword can only fool TypeScript into letting you do what you think you are doing.

With TypeScript 3 this might be the only way.

If you are using TypeScript 4+, you can enforce some validation on the resulting `fieldKey`, by using a [Template Literal Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type MyField = `field_${number}`;
type MyType = Record<MyField, string>;

const myFactory = (instance: MyType): string => {
    let n = 12;
    const fieldName: keyof MyType = `field_${n}`;
    return instance[fieldName];
}
```

In this snippet, if you had given a non-number value to `n`, (such as `"x"`) then it would yield to `"field_x"` which is rejected (i.e. detected as improper, by TypeScript at compile-time).

Same as if you write :

```
const fieldName: keyof MyType = `wrong_${n}`;
```

because `wrong_12` is not valid in `MyType`.

If you need to build a larger `MyType` with additional fields not in the same shape as `field_N`, you could declare:

```
type LargerType = MyType & {
    anotherField: string;
};
```

Finally, if you need to limit the numbers, you could declare:

```
type MyField = `field_${1 | 2 | 3 | 4}`;
```

In this case, the snippet with `n = 12` yields an error because `12` is already known to be forbidden. If the `n` value was obtained dynamically instead of inferred like here, it would need to be *declared* as:

```
let n: 1|2|3|4;
```

(or more likely, you would declare a `type` for the accepted numbers, since now you're using them in several places.)